# How to get property from object to publish as post?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, backend

I need to get property of data, but i am geting only object in object, no specific property as email, title...
I need this to publish users posts. I already tried with  STRINGIFY  , but it does not work.

--BACKEND--

```
app.get ('/galerija', async (req , res) => {
    let db = await connect();
    let cursor = await db.collection('galerija').find();
    let results = await cursor.toArray();

    res.json(results);
});
```

--VUE--

```
async dohvatiObjavu(){
            this.objave = await Objave.dohvati_objavu();
            console.log("Postovi sa galerija: " + this.objave.naslov);
}
```

--SERVICES--

```
async dohvati_objavu() {

        let response = await Service.get(/galerija);
        console.log(response);
        let data = response.data;

        console.log("Current posts in services:" + {data})
        data=data.map((doc)=>{
        return {
            id: doc._id,
                email: doc.email,
                naslov: doc.naslov,
                noviOpisSlike: doc.noviOpisSlike,
                slika: doc.slikaReference,
        }
        });
        return data;


    },
```

CONSOLE

[image]

Comment: What does get() return? What is service?

Comment: why are you using JSON.stringify when the returned array (data) from the back end contains only objects?

Comment: i refreshed photo of console so you can see what i get from *get*,  service is just connection between frontend and backend, it has axios inside

Comment: try data[0]['email'];